# Get all images from JSON using node.js with ejs view

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

I'm learning node.js and I came to a problem where I need to display all images from JSON array to front end using ejs view. 
My JSON looks like this:

```
[
{
    "id":1,
    "avatar":"../img/hof/Biba.jpg",
    "position":1,
    "cups":[
        "../img/pokal_euro.png",
        "../img/pokal_lp.png",
        "../img/pokal_wc.png"
    ],
    "points":634,
    "prize":852
}
```

]

My ejs file where Im trying to call images is like this

```
<% dataSorted.forEach(function(dat) { %>
       <img src="<%= dat.avatar %>">
        <div class="mesto"><h1><%= dat.position %></h1></div>
        <div class="cups">
        <img src="<%= dat.cups[0] %>" class="pokal"/>
        </div>
        <h4 class="levo"><%= dat.points %> točk</h4>
        <h4 class="desno"><%= dat.prize %>€</h4>
  <% }); %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over cups, so if cups in dataSorted:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < dataSorted['cups'].length; i++) { %>
    <div class="cups">
        <img src="<%= dataSorted['cups'][i] %>"/>
    </div>
<% }; %>
```

**Update**

If understand your question correctly you need to show all images for all items:

```
<% dataSorted.forEach(function(dat) { %>
       <img src="<%= dat.avatar %>">
        <div class="mesto"><h1><%= dat.position %></h1></div>
        <% for (var i = 0; i < dat['cups'].length; i++) { %>
            <div class="cups">
                <img src="<%= dat['cups'][i] %>"/>
            </div>
        <% }; %>
        <h4 class="levo"><%= dat.points %> točk</h4>
        <h4 class="desno"><%= dat.prize %>€</h4>
  <% }); %>
```

Comment: ok, I understand. But there is a problem. I have more than just cups in JSON. I updated code. How can I get images now?

Comment: Now it gives me error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"